# Martensitic transformation in ceramics

Tags: materials

What is the specification of Martensite (displacive) transformation in ceramics comparing to the metals? I just know about Martensite transformation in metals. For example, these transformations are thermal and diffusionless. Also, the kinetic and morphology are dominant by strain energy.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Kelly, P. M., Francis Rose, L.R., The martensitic transformation in ceramics — its role in transformation toughening, Progress in Materials Science, 2002, Vol.47(5):463–557, doi:10.1016/S0079-6425(00)00005-0](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0079642500000050).

Basically, a transformation is martensitic if it occurs from a collective shear motion of the atoms where each atomic displacement is less than the distance between atoms.  There is no diffusion (atoms moving to other lattice sites). The definition is the same as in a metal, but in a ceramic you have multiple atom types in the crystal, that's all.